# How to include "Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'" in a sed command?

Tags: command-line, sed

I used

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log > ~/Desktop/allhistory.log && zcat /var/log/apt/history.log*gz >> ~/Desktop/allhistory.log
```

to create *~/Desktop/allhistory.log*.

I can run

```
sed -r -i.1 '/(^Commandline: apt-get --no-upgrade|^Commandline: apt full-upgrade|^Upgrade: |^End-Date: |^Error: |^Requested-By: |^Commandline: apt-get autoremove|^Commandline: apt autoremove|^Commandline: apt-get --yes|Commandline: apt-get purge|Commandline: apt purge|^Remove: |^Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade|^Install: |Commandline: aptdaemon|--reinstall|^Commandline: apt-get --yes --no-install-recommends|^Purge:|^Reinstall )/d' allhistory.log
```

to exclude stuff I don't want. But I also want to include

```
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
```

When I try

```
sed -r -i.1 '/(^Commandline: packagekit role=\'update-packages\'|^Commandline: apt-get --no-upgrade|^Commandline: apt full-upgrade|^Upgrade: |^End-Date: |^Error: |^Requested-By: |^Commandline: apt-get autoremove|^Commandline: apt autoremove|^Commandline: apt-get --yes|Commandline: apt-get purge|Commandline: apt purge|^Remove: |^Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade|^Install: |Commandline: aptdaemon|--reinstall|^Commandline: apt-get --yes --no-install-recommends|^Purge:|^Reinstall )/d' allhistory.log
```

I get

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

What do I need to do to include *Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'* successfully in the *sed* command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queston boils down to *"How do I quote/use single quotes inside a single quoted string"*?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/5830574) over on stackoverflow.com explains it. Use

```
sed -r -i.1 '/(^Commandline: packagekit role='"'"'update-packages'"'"'|^Commandline: apt-get --no-upgrade|
               ^Commandline: apt full-upgrade|
               ....|
               ^Reinstall )/d' allhistory.log
```

(I added newlines for readability. Drop them in the actual command.)

Basically it is: Replace each inner `'` with `'"'"'`. That is:

- end the first string with `'`,
- append a literal `'` inside double quotes (`"'"`),
- append the next part of the string again starting with `'`

If you consider this unreadable then you are right. 
It is because *bash* does not have a nice string concatenation operator like
other language do. If there was such an operator (`+`, for example), then
it would look like this:

```
sed … '...role=' + "'" + 'update-packages' + "'" + '|^Commandline…'
#      ssssssss     d     sssssssssssssss     d     ssssssssssssss
```

Here the `s`es denote a single quoted string and the `d`s the double quoted
single-quote in-between. Since there is no such `+` operator in bash you need
to stick them together without any spaces in-between and that gives `'"'"'`.

Comment: Personally I find the `'\''` quoting style easier to read than `'"'"'`

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, that's another possibility. A matter of taste, I guess. My mnemonic is "SDSDS" (single-double-single-double-single). Yours must be different ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since there are no characters in your regex pattern that the shell will expand when inside double quotes (such as `$` or `!` for example), you can simply use double quotes around the whole expression:

```
$ echo "foo 'bar' baz" | sed "s/'bar'/'BAR'/"
foo 'BAR' baz
```

See for example [Single quote within double quotes and the Bash reference manual](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508/single-quote-within-double-quotes-and-the-bash-reference-manual)